# Запрос в Sqlite3 с использованием переменной

Tags: python, запрос, sqlite3, переменные

при попытке запустить запрос в базу данных с использованием заранее заданной переменной выводится нулевое значение и запрос соответственно не исполняется, в то же время, если подставить вместо переменной само строковое значение напрямую, то запрос исполняется. Голову сломал, не пойму в чем беда.

```
contractNum = pyperclip.paste() 

import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('pk2.sqlite3')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute(f"SELECT cession, bank FROM pk2 WHERE contract LIKE '{contractNum}'")
print(c.fetchone())
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: вы затрудяете помощь. вам следует показать содержимое contractNum, а также сформировать отдельно сам select что бы можно было его увидеть. также вы не привели код и текст возвращаемой ошибки. как вам помочь без этого?   например, ваш селект выглядит так select * from tbl where code in ('123',), и это неправильно

Comment: `c.execute("SELECT cession, bank FROM pk2 WHERE contract LIKE ?", contractNum)`